# Concurrency issue for SQL server transactions for a table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have inherited a system where there is a table X where points are allocated to users. Below is an example of how this looks like -

[image]

When a row is added the NewBalance is the actual total balance for the user.

How this is done is in a transaction (I am attaching values which are dynamically passed):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @userId uniqueidentifier = 'DA04C99F-575A-434F-BD69-05F2C111360E'
DECLARE @oldBalance int
DECLARE @newPoints int = 25
SELECT TOP 1 @oldBalance = NewBalance FROM X WHERE UserId =  ORDER BY [Date] 
DESC
INSERT INTO X (UserId, Date, Value, NewBalance) VALUES (@userId, 
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), @newPoints, @oldBalance + @newPoints)
END
```

The above piece of code can be called from multiple modules to add points each of which are running in different isolation levels. It is also possible that this gets called concurrently from 2 different modules - so we end up with something like this -

[image]

Obviously 2 different transactions read the same row while fetching the initial @oldBalance and then each added to it resulting in the problem.

We are thinking of making all modules that call this piece of code to run under Serializable isolation level. But we are having trouble replicating the problem in lower environments and so there is no realistic way to test.

Also, from what I understand irrespective of isolation level the SELECT TOP 1 will always place a shared lock on the row so it can be read by other transactions.

Any tips or reading material to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I *think* the real problem is you're storing aggregated values in your table. Instead of storing them, you should be calculating them at `SELECT`; then you won't have this problem.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu. It will be easier if you have one row for each user - update it's balance and reason and create a history table using trigger or system versioning table which will give the history of changes.

Comment: I don't mean update the value of balance at all, @gotqn . In fact, I mean to say that it shouldn't even be in the table. I'm suggesting that balance should be calculated with a windowed `SUM` expression; which if the OP wants to easily reference could be exposed in a `VIEW`.

Comment: I agree with both of you and both the suggestions are perfectly valid and how I would have done this myself - this is however an inherited design and the application is LIVE with over 250k users. I already thought of doing this but just wanting to check if there is an easier solution before going for this drastic change. The table in question has over 400 million rows - It is also strange that this issue was not spotted earlier - but we are where we are.

Comment: Sure,  I agree with you that aggregation of the balance can be done easily on read (for example using SUM with ORDER BY) and also offer second approach - to have only one row per user and history table showing the changes. In my case there is no need to store the value, as it can be calculated using the balance.

Comment: I would do it like @Lamu suggests with a VIEW for the SUM and not store the total balance at all.

Comment: @PriyankarDutta Yes. calculating the balance in `VIEW` will be the easier way.

Comment: The other approach (which I'm not a fan of) would be to add the `UPDLOCK` [table hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15) to the query that get's the value of `balance`. That would stop any other queries, provided they aren't (foolishly) using a table hint like `NOLOCK`, from being able to obtain the value of `balance` until the transaction where the `UPDLOCK` hint was used completes.

Comment: I assume that,  If you want to lock the rows in the select statement you can use the WITH(XLOCK, ROWLOCK) hint so nobody can access these rows until the COMMIT/ROLLBACK statement. However , it will increase performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much changeability you have over the table structure itself, you could do as others have suggested restrict it to a single row to show only the current row and then use a lock on the table.

You could also implement a counter type for each of the unique records so the current iteration of data inserted is always sequential because you're checking if it's been updated since you started your update.

I have added a simple way of doing the update using a procedure rather than just inserting. I am not aware of your application or database, but if you are able to read the output and store the balance to add you are able to implement a retry until the values match and it enables the insert.

```
CREATE TABLE X (UserId UniqueIdentifier, Date DATETIME, Value INT, NewBalance INT)
INSERT INTO X VALUES (NEWID(), GETUTCDATE(),10,10)

SELECT * FROM X

BEGIN
DECLARE @userId uniqueidentifier = '5396C445-8AC1-4B46-8E25-A416059D7976'
DECLARE @oldBalance int
DECLARE @newPoints int = 25
SELECT TOP 1 @oldBalance = NewBalance FROM X WHERE UserId = @userId ORDER BY [Date] DESC

EXEC dbo.usp_Update_X @userId, @oldBalance, @newPoints

END

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Update_X 
(
 @UserID UniqueIdentifier
,@OldBalance INT
,@newPoints INT
)
AS

IF @OldBalance = (SELECT  TOP 1 NewBalance FROM X WHERE UserId = @UserID ORDER BY Date DESC)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO X (UserId, Date, Value, NewBalance) VALUES (@userId, 
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), @newPoints, @oldBalance + @newPoints)
Print 'Inserted Successfully'
END
ELSE
Print 'Changed - Get Balance Again'

GO
```

Once something like this has been implemented, you could then periodically check to ensure the values go in the correct order

```
SELECT UserId, Date, NewBalance, Value, SUM(Value) OVER (Partition By UserId ORDER BY Date ASC) AS NewBalanceCheck
FROM X
```

Comment: Thanks - this does cause the select to be computed twice but something we can try. I will accept this as the answer because I believe this is an attempt to solve the problem without changing the parameters of the existing problem.